# Mixing virtual inheritance and template specialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, template-specialization, virtual-functions

I am trying to write a small deserialization module that would decode strings into bools/integers/enums/strings depending on a static type, so that I could write something along the lines of

```
enum E { zero, one, two };

struct X {
    deser<bool> a;
    deser<signed> b;
    deser<E> c;
    deser<std::string> d;
    deser_list_t desers;

    X() 
        : a(false, std::vector<std::string>{ "yes", "true" }, std::vector<std::string>{ "no", "false" })
        , b(-1), c(zero), d()
    { 
        desers.add("a", a).add("b", b).add("c", c).add("d", d); // by refs?..
    }

    void deserialize(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& many_data) {
        desers.process(many_data);
        if (!d.is_there()) { throw chair_t(); }
    }
};
```

What did I try: declare a non-template class `deser_base` with pure virtual `bool parse(const std::string& value)`, declare a derived template class `deser<T>` (with `deser(T default_value)` constructor) — now I have to specialize it somehow for bools/integers/enums/strings.

And that's what I do not know how to do: `bool` specialization needs two additional members (and a special constructor), `std::string` specialization doesn't need a default value.

Should I instead derive `deser_bool`, `deser_number<T>`, etc. from `deser_base` and then make `deser<T>` a wrapper around them?

Comment: Specializations can have any members you like - I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @KerrekSB They also don't have any members from the generic declaration, it seems: any member I declared in `deser<T>` is not available in `deser<bool>`.

Comment: No, of course not. A template specialization is a completely separate class. (All this should be in your text book...?)

Comment: clearly you are doing doing wrong which we cannot see here. Template specialization, as I am sure you already know is just defining behavior for a particular data type.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, it *is* said in my textbook, but... well. There are still some things in `deser<T>` that are always done the same way for every `T` specialization, but I can't put them into `deser_base` — it's not templated. Also, I what is the actual way to specialize for enums? Writing `template <typename T> deser<typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type> { ... };` doesn't quite work

Comment: You can have additional classes or templates to serve as common implementation bases... say `template <> struct deser<E> { /* ... */ };`

Comment: @KerrekSB Fair enough. However, suppose I want a two-stage deserialization for enums: first, I try to parse the string as a number, then pass it to `bool enum_from_number<Enum>(typename get_integral<Enum>::type val, Enum& result)`, if it fails, I try `bool enum_from_string<Enum>(const std::string& val, Enum& result)`, and if it fails, so be it. This algorithm factors out, so I can write only `enum_from_number/string` specializations for needed enums... but only if I can make `deser<T>::parse()` use it if `T` is an enum. Is it should be done with specializtion?